# orthogonal polynomials in (-1,1) with a modified weight function

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

I would like to find the orthogonal polynomial system   $ \{ P_n(x), n \in \textbf{Z} \} $ corresponding to the weight function $ w(x) = \frac { 1} {\sqrt{1-x^2} (1+\sqrt{1-x^2} ) } $  defined on the interval $(-1,1)$. Noticing that this $w(x)$ is a modified Chebyshev weight function, I am just wondering whether the solution to this problem studied previously. I am not sure about it.  Your responses are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these polynomials are known.
First substitute $x = \cos(\theta)$, such that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} p_m(\cos(\theta))p_n(\cos(\theta)) \frac{d\theta}{(1 + \sin(\theta))}.
$$
Now substitute $\nu = \sin(\theta)$, then 
$$
d\nu/d\theta = \cos(\theta) = \sqrt{(1 - \sin(\theta)^2)} = \sqrt{(1 - \nu^2)} = \sqrt{(1 - \nu)}\sqrt{(1 + \nu)},
$$
such that the orthogonality relation is equivalent to
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} p_m(\nu) p_n(\nu) (1 + \nu)^{-\frac{3}{2}}(1 - \nu)^{-\frac{1}{2}} d\nu.
$$
The weight $w(\nu) = (1 + \nu)^{-\frac{3}{2}}(1 - \nu)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ corresponds to the Jacobi polynomials $P_m^{(-1/2, -3/2)}(\nu)$.
Under this identification you basically study well known polynomials.

Comment: The very first integral should be with a $+$ sign and between $0$ and $\pi$; besides that, I agree that they are just Jacobi polynomials.

Comment: @Noud,  There is a serious problem with second substitution $\nu= \sin \theta $.  We will get $ d\nu = \cos \theta d \theta $  or $ \frac {d \theta } {(1 + \sin \theta ) } = \frac {d\nu} {(1+\nu)^{\frac{3}{2}} (1-\nu)^{\frac{1}{2} }} $.  So the integral becomes $ \int_{0}^{0} p_m(\sqrt(1-\nu^2) p_n(\sqrt(1-\nu^2) \frac {d\nu} {(1+\nu)^(3/2) (1-\nu)^1/2 } $.

Comment: @Noud,  there is a problem with limits of the integral with this substitution, also the arguments of $p_m$ and $p_n$ is not $\nu$ .

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, you're right. Thank you.

Comment: @JRS, you're right about the substitution, I overlooked minus signs. I don't understand your (serious) problem with limits and substitutions. The polynomials you're studying can be identified with Jacobi polynomials with the correct substitution. I'm not giving the substitution explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Noud. For the answer.  Noticing that the weight function $ w(x) = d \eta(x) $ where $ \eta(x) = \left(  \frac { \sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x} }  { \sqrt{1+x} + \sqrt{1-x} } \right) $ .  Thus from  $ \int_{x=-1}^{1} p_m(x) p_n(x) dx $ , we get $ \int_{x=-1}^{1} p_m(\eta(x) ) p_n(\eta(x) ) w(x) dx $ . what I I mean is, $p_m \circ \eta $  and $ p_n \circ \eta $  are orthogonal functions but not the required polynomials.

Comment: @Noud, about the problem with limits of integration.  $ x = \cos \theta $ changes the interval of integration from $ (-1 , 1) $ to $ (0, \pi) $ . The substitution $ \nu = \sin \theta $ changes the interval of integration from $( 0, \pi) $ to $ (0, 0) $ . That I think is inconsistent. Please correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: Dear @JRS, you should look at this integration as if you're integrating over the unit circle. (this is actually a common thing to do with orthogonal polynomials, e.g. see the whole ($q$-)Askey scheme) On $(0,\pi)$, $\nu$ ranges between $0$ to $1$. But you also add the $(\pi, 2\pi)$ part of the circle, so that $\nu$ ranges between $-1$ and $0$. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Noud, That is very interesting. Can you point to some references on integrating over unit circle. Thanks for info.

Comment: @JRS, Number 319 of the memoirs of the AMS by Askey and Wilson is a classic. Ismail ``Classical and quantum orthogonal polynomials in one variable'' also contains a lot on measures on the unit circle corresponding to orthogonal polynomials. Basically look for Askey-Wilson polynomials in general.

Answer (score 0):

The integral $ \int_{x=-1}^{+1} \frac {dx} {\sqrt{1-x^2} (1 + \sqrt{1-x^2}) } = \int_{x=-1}^{0} \frac {dx} {\sqrt{1-x^2} (1 + \sqrt{1-x^2} )} + \int_{x=0}^{1} \frac {dx} {\sqrt{1-x^2} (1 + \sqrt{1-x^2} )} $.

Using  substitutions $ s \rightarrow -\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $t \rightarrow\sqrt{1-x^2} $ respectively in to the first and second integrals on the right-hand side gives

$ \int_{x=-1}^{+1} \frac {dx} {\sqrt{1-x^2} (1 + \sqrt{1-x^2}) } = 
 - \int_{s=-1}^{0} \frac{ds}{(1+s)^{ \frac{1}{2}} (1-s)^{\frac{3}{2}}} +
  \int_{t=0}^{1} \frac{dt}{(1+t)^{ \frac{3}{2}} (1-t)^{\frac{1}{2}}} $ .

Thus, the resulting polynomial space appears to be

$L_2[(-1,1),w(x)] =L_2[(-1,0),w_1] \cup L_2[(0,1),w_2] $.
Where 
$ w(x) = \frac{1} { \sqrt{1-x^2} (1+\sqrt{1-x^2} ) }$  ,
$w_1(x) = \frac{-1} { (1+x)^{1/2} (1-x)^{3/2 } } $ and
$w_2(x) = \frac{1} { (1+x)^{3/2} (1-x)^{1/2 } } $.

So two different beta distributions for the half-intervals of $(-1,1)$, leading to two different orthogonal polynomial sequences there.

Comment: Dear @Noud, Attempted to refine the results based on your suggestions.